# DataGrid, ItemsSource и наследование

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Есть класс

```
public class MyClass
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Есть его наследник

```
public class MyClassEx : MyClass
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Есть ViewModel

```
public class Vm
{
  public ObservableCollection<MyClass> Items { get; set; }

  public Vm()
  {
    Items = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
    Items.Add(new MyClassEx());
  }
}
```

Ну и в Xaml есть `DataGrid` у которого `ItemsSource` биндится к `Vm.Items`. Так вот столбцы генерируются из класса `MyClass`, то есть один столбец Id. А как мне, не создавая дополнительных `View`, сделать так, чтобы столбцы были созданы автоматически для полей наследников, которые присутствуют в коллекции?

Comment: посмотрите здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983033/how-do-i-dynamically-generate-columns-in-a-wpf-datagrid

Comment: @S.Kost, добавить нужные столбцы в коде я знаю как, но воспользуюсь этим в самом крайнем случае, если не найду других вариантов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю с такими условиями это невозможно, т.к. при автогенерации используется список свойств конкретного типа для создания колонок.

Возможные решения: 

!!!Edited* Поменять тип коллекции на object, как показал тест это даст результат которого вы и хотели.

1. Использование другого ВМ с `ObservableCollection<MyClassEx> Items`, но думаю этот вариант не рассматривается т.к. имеется множество различных наследников, на каждый свой ВМ не сделаешь.
2. Явное определение столбцов и биндингов в xaml (что противоречит условию об автогенерации столбцов)
3. Ручное заполнение таблицы (как уже было предложено в комментариях)
4. Реализовать свою DataGrid с измененным механизмом генерации столбцов. (но это уже скорее боян, а не вариант )

PS На комментарий репы нету))

Comment: "Думаю с такими условиями это невозможно, т.к. при автогенерации используется список свойств конкретного типа для создания колонок." В том и дело, что текущий тип (если, конечно, брать тип объекта а не элемента коллекции) будет верным. `obj.GetType()` вернет `typeof(MyClassEx)`

Comment: Имелся в виду именно тип коллекции. Как я думаю (как это происходит на самом деле не видел), получается список свойств для типа коллекции. Для каждого свойства создается колонка с биндингом к данным, т.е. происходит автоматизация ручного создания колонок в xaml, это и есть 'AutogenerateColumns = true'

Comment: Дело в том, что изменение типа коллекции на object ничего не меняется. при том, что я даже полностью заполнил ее объектами типа MyClassEx

Comment: Странно только что проверил с коллекцией object'ов и тиблица генирировалась как раз так, как вы хотели. Со всеми полями MyClassEx, у объектов MyClass это поле оставалось пустым. Так что изменение типа коллекции на Object должно быть решением!